# libgdx click area above target

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to make a simple main menu with clickable play and exit labels, but clickable area is always above labels. To click "play" label I need to click about 20 pixels above it.

How can I align clickable area with labels?

There is my MainMenuButton class

```
public class MainMenuButtons {
    private MainGame game;
    private Stage stage;
    private Viewport gameViewport;

    private Label mainGameLabel, playLabel, exitLabel;

    public MainMenuButtons(MainGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        gameViewport = new FillViewport(GameInfo.WIDTH, GameInfo.HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
        stage = new Stage(gameViewport, game.getBatch());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


        createLabelsAndButtons();
        addAllListeners();

        Table menuTable = new Table();
        menuTable.center().center();
        menuTable.setFillParent(true);
        menuTable.add(playLabel);
        menuTable.row();
        menuTable.add(exitLabel).padTop(40);


        Table gameTitle = new Table();
        gameTitle.center().top();
        gameTitle.setFillParent(true);
        gameTitle.add(mainGameLabel).padTop(40);

        menuTable.debug();
        stage.addActor(menuTable);
        stage.addActor(gameTitle);

    }

    void createLabelsAndButtons() {
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/PressStart2P.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 45;

        BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        mainGameLabel = new Label("Road Racer", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));


        parameter.size = 25;

        font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        playLabel = new Label("Play", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));
        exitLabel = new Label("Exit", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));
    }

    void addAllListeners() {

        playLabel.addListener(new ClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
                System.out.println("Play label clicked " + y);
//                game.setScreen(new GamePlay(game));
            }
        });

        exitLabel.addListener(new ClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
                System.out.println("Exit label clicked " + y);
//                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });



    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return this.stage;
    }


}
```

And I call it in the MainMenu class

```
/**
 * Created by vladk on 24/09/16.
 */
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    private MainGame game;
    private OrthographicCamera mainCamera;
    private Viewport gameViewport;

    private MainMenuButtons btns;

    public MainMenu(MainGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        mainCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        mainCamera.setToOrtho(false, GameInfo.WIDTH, GameInfo.HEIGHT);
        mainCamera.position.set(GameInfo.WIDTH / 2f, GameInfo.HEIGHT / 2f, 0);

        gameViewport = new StretchViewport(GameInfo.WIDTH, GameInfo.HEIGHT, mainCamera);

        // background ??

        // buttons
        btns = new MainMenuButtons(game);
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//        game.getBatch().begin();
//        game.getBatch().end();

        game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(btns.getStage().getCamera().combined);
        btns.getStage().draw();
        btns.getStage().act();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gameViewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // bg
        // buttons
        btns.getStage().dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I needed to update view port for the MainMenuButtons, so I created a new method

```
// in the MainMenuButtons class
public void viewportUpdate(int width, int height) {
    gameViewport.update(width, height);
}
```

and call if from the MainMenu class

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gameViewport.update(width, height);
    btns.viewportUpdate(width, height);
}
```